# Typescript, same class but different property types?

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript and angular.

I have 2 service that are very similar, but the property are different :

```
  synchronizedMaps: Map<string, Map<string, MapSynchSettings>> = new Map<string, Map<string, MapSynchSettings>>();
  groupDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<SynchMapGroupSubject>> = new Map<string, Subject<SynchMapGroupSubject>> ();
  mapDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<SynchMapSubject>> = new Map<string, Subject<SynchMapSubject>> ();

  public createNewSynchGroup(id?: string): Observable<SynchMapGroupSubject> {

    this.synchronizedMaps.set(id, new Map<string, MapSynchSettings>());
    this.groupDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<SynchMapGroupSubject>());
    this.mapDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<SynchMapSubject>());

    return this.groupDispatchers.get(id).asObservable();
}
```

and

```
  synchronizedDrawer: Map<string, Map<string, SynchWaypointDrawerSettings>> = new Map<string, Map<string, SynchWaypointDrawerSettings>>();
  groupDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject>> = new Map<string, Subject<SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject>> ();
  waypointDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<SynchWaypointSubject>> = new Map<string, Subject<SynchWaypointSubject>> ();

  constructor() { }

  public createNewSynchGroup(id?: string): Observable<SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject> {
    this.synchronizedDrawer.set(id, new Map<string, SynchWaypointDrawerSettings>());
    this.groupDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject>());
    this.waypointDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<SynchWaypointSubject>());

    return this.groupDispatchers.get(id).asObservable();
}
```

The property type, and the method returned value change, but the method implementation and logic of those 2 service are exactly the same.

I wanted to know if there is a method to merge those 2 service into a single one, or make a parent class that I can extend with just the variable types but all the name and logic will be kept the same.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes), where you use a type parameter for each type you want to specify later:

```
class GeneralThing<S, G, T> {
    synchronized: Map<string, Map<string, S>> = new Map();
    groupDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<G>> = new Map();
    subjectDispatchers: Map<string, Subject<T>> = new Map();

    public createNewSynchGroup(id?: string): Observable<G> {
        if (!id) throw new Error("What?!");

        this.synchronized.set(id, new Map());
        this.groupDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<G>());
        this.subjectDispatchers.set(id, new Subject<T>());

        return this.groupDispatchers.get(id)!.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In the above, I've changed the property names to something general (so just `synchronized` and `subjectDispatchers`) and used the type parameters `S`, `G`, and `T`.

Then you can specify the two services as

```
GeneralThing<MapSynchSettings, SynchMapGroupSubject, SynchMapSubject>
```

and

```
GeneralThing<SynchWaypointDrawerSettings, SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject, SynchWaypointSubject>
```

Or you could give them concrete names like

```
class MapThing extends GeneralThing<
  MapSynchSettings, 
  SynchMapGroupSubject, 
  SynchMapSubject
> {}

class WaypointDrawerThing extends GeneralThing<
  SynchWaypointDrawerSettings, 
  SynchWaypointDrawerGroupSubject, 
  SynchWaypointSubject
> {}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I was thinking something like that, I didn't know I could do it on many different types, definitely the solution thanks